# How can I learn air traffic control as a high-schooler?

Tags: air-traffic-control

I really love aviation and I'm thinking about going for a career in air traffic control, but I can't find anything on the web that will help me learn all about it and how to perform basic operations. Is there anything on the web that I could use?

Comment: @Dave this didnt help me much though.

Comment: this will most likely get closed as the other answer does cover the question pretty explicitly. I have un-deleted an answer here I was working on before I noticed the dupe. It has some more info in it as well.

Comment: Call your local control tower and ask to take a tour.

Answer (score 2):

Join the [Vatsim](https://www.vatsim.net/) network.  This is a network of simulated pilots flying X-Plane, FSX, etc., *and* simulated controllers.  The simulated controllers use, as much as they can in a hobbyist network, real phraseology and procedures.  I personally knew several real-world controllers who controlled on the Vatsim network in their off-time, and I know several hobbyist controllers who went on to become real air traffic controllers.

While controlling on a hobby network is not the same as controlling real airplanes, you won't learn a lot you'll have to relearn.  That's because the hobbyist controllers on Vatsim make a serious effort to follow real procedures.  When they discuss air traffic control with each other, you frequently see references to the [".65"](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf), the official bible of ATC.

Answer (score 1):

The FAA lists a lot of the [ATC info here](https://www.faa.gov/jobs/career_fields/aviation_careers/). They also offer a really nice ["example" flight worth of communication](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_across_america/) for those interested in what its like.

You can stream the US ATC feeds from [most major airports from this site](https://www.liveatc.net/). A good resource once you have some context on what they are saying.

The [airplane instrument flying handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/FAA-H-8083-15B.pdf) is intended for pilots but has lots of [IFR flying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_flight_rules) examples and information with ATC communications as well.

My local airport offers (or at least offered at one point) tours of the tower. You can usually set one up by [calling the phone number for the field.](https://www.aopa.org/airports/KPNE) This is a neat way to see at least part of the working environment and possibly meet a controller and ask them questions.